# Non-Uniform Spherical Distributions

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution, circular-statistics

Suppose $X_i\overset{\text{iid}}{\sim} N(0,1)$, and define the random vector $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. Then the normalized vector $\mathbf{Z}:=\frac{\mathbf{X}}{\|\mathbf{X}\|_2}$ is uniformly distributed on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Several properties of the distribution of $\mathbf{Z}$ are known, e.g.,

1. All odd moments are $\mathbf{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$
2. Cross-term/second moments: $\mathbb{E}[Z_iZ_j]=n^{-1}\mathbb{1}(i=j)$

(More properties of higher order moments are listed in Chapter 9 of Mardia and Jupp's *Directional Statistics* [textbook](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470316979).)

My question is: what happens if we define $X_i\overset{\text{ind}}{\sim}N(0,\sigma_i^2)$, more generally? One could rely on symmetry arguments to show that Property 1 above still holds for the normalized vector $\mathbf{Z}$, but is there a straightforward way to obtain second and higher order moments of $\mathbf{Z}$? I am most keen to be pointed to any references or techniques (recurrences or recursions perhaps?) for deriving these quantities. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A similar spherical distribution (but not the same because of a different construction method without projection) is the [Von Mises-Fisher distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises%E2%80%93Fisher_distribution).

Comment: Shouldn't the expectation of $Z_iZ_j$ be zero as well for $i\neq j$ because of symmetry? Maybe you refere to the expectation of the absolute value?

Comment: Thanks for the comments @SextusEmpiricus. Yes I am aware of the Von Mises-Fisher distribution. Also, you are right re: Property 2 for $i\neq j$; I have that covered by the indicator function.

Comment: I am looking for a generalization to a collection of independent but not necessarily identically distributed zero-mean Gaussians.

Comment: I see. To be more specific, I'm interested in the second moments. But I suspect the way to derive the second moment might reveal general techniques that allow one to work up to higher moments. Thus I phrased my question more broadly.

Comment: I was asking for the way that you want to generalize the distributions. But I see now that the generalisation are just to change the variance?

Comment: The moments of $X$ are found by multiplying the moments of $Z$ by suitable products of powers of the $\sigma_i$ because *all you are doing is changing the units of measurement of the $Z_i.$*  That looks so trivial that I am led to wonder whether you have something more complicated in mind where you refer to "higher order moments of $Z.$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two dimensions, the second moments $E[Z_i^2]$ have a simple formula, which implies that those moments are proportional to the standard deviations of the variables.

Suppose $X_i$ and $X_j$ have standard deviations $s$ and $t$. By considering these as dilations of two standard normals,
$$(X_i,X_j)\sim (Rs\cos\theta,Rt\sin\theta)$$
where $\theta$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2\pi]$, and the distribution of $R$ is half-normal but irrelevant. By substituting $u=(t \tan\theta)/s$, and then integrating with the method of partial fractions,
$$Z_i^2=\frac{(Rs\cos\theta)^2}{(Rs\cos\theta)^2 + (Rt\sin\theta)^2}$$
\begin{align}
E[Z_i^2] &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\!
\frac{s^2\cos^2\theta}{s^2\cos^2\theta + t^2\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{2}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1+u^2}\frac{(t/s)\,du}{(t/s)^2+u^2}\\
&=\frac{s}{s+t}
\end{align}
Similarly $E[Z_j^2]=t/(s+t)$. In the special case mentioned in the post of identical standard deviations, this gives the expected value of $1/2$.

Comment: This argument makes sense. Thanks! I will see if there is a way to generalize, and post an update if I find something.